# Twisted http gzip support

Tags: python, gzip, twisted

I'm looking to help an open source project with Python.
As far as I could tell, Twisted <strike>doesn't</strike> [didn't](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/104) support  sending and receiving gzip information with HTTP (as of 2011).
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/104

Google seems to confirm it, since I couldn't find any mention of it the documentation.
My question is whether I'm right about this, or if this has changed?
Alternatively, is it actually useful to anyone? I guess there's a reason it hasn't been implemented yet.

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask...

Comment: I suspect that many people who care about HTTP gzip compression are running their twisted.web applications behind another HTTP server such as Apache or nginx. Thus, having support for it in twisted.web is not particularly interesting or important. That said, there's no reason why everyone should *have* to run their application in a setup like that. As usual, the answer to "why isn't this implemented yet?" is just "nobody has done the work yet"...

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible using [Resource Encoders](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#request-encoders). Quoting from that link:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site, GzipEncoderFactory
from twisted.web.resource import Resource, EncodingResourceWrapper
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Simple(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html>Hello, world!</html>"

resource = Simple()
wrapped = EncodingResourceWrapper(resource, [GzipEncoderFactory()])
site = Site(wrapped)
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

See the link for more information. The ticket in the question is now closed as well.

Comment: It's important to note that in this example, isLeaf is set to true, so the wrapped resource will be recognized as having the encoder. If isLeaf is not true, then getChild will be called, and that may not be wrapped by the EncodingResourceWrapper.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for [`EncodingResourceWrapper`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.resource.EncodingResourceWrapper.html):

> Note that the returned children resources won't be wrapped, so you
>   have to explicitly wrap them if you want the encoding to be applied.

So if a `Resource` implements `getChild`, then you need to wrap that resource as well.
For example:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site, GzipEncoderFactory
from twisted.web.resource import EncodingResourceWrapper
from twisted.web import static
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
import sys
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

class WebServer(static.File):        
    def getChild(self, path, request):
        child = static.File.getChild(self, path, request)            
        return EncodingResourceWrapper(child, [GzipEncoderFactory()])

resource = WebServer('/tmp')

site = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

you can test it with **netcat**:

```
printf 'GET /  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' | nc localhost 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

The ticket is still open, so it is correct that this feature is still not available in Twisted.  However, Nevow includes support for sending gzipped responses: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~divmod-dev/divmod.org/trunk/view/head:/Nevow/nevow/compression.py.  Since Nevow can Twisted Web can easily be used together, this might be a way to get what you want.

Hopefully the feature will also be ported from Nevow to Twisted Web someday as well.

Comment: If his goal is to help an open source project with Python, then porting this feature from Nevow to Twisted would be an excellent way to do it!

Comment: Porting nevow.compression to twisted.web should be relatively easy; I believe the only major changes required would be to delete the finishRequest insanity that Nevow's request API requires, and instead override IRequest.finish in its place.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand a bit @danbrough's great answer in case someone else lands here:
Fist of all, if you happen to put children with `IResource.putChild`, his solution won't work directly, you'll have to overwrite `IResource.getChildWithDefault` instead of just `IResource.getChild`.

It also happens, that having some resources protected with `HTTP BasicAuthentication` **and** serving them compressed with `Gzip` is a bit trickier, since the above won't work. In this case you'll need to fiddle with the `HTTPAuthSessionWrapper` like this:

```
class GzipAuthSessionWrapper(HTTPAuthSessionWrapper):
  def getChildWithDefault(self, path, request):
    child = HTTPAuthSessionWrapper.getChildWithDefault(self, path, request)
    gzipChild = EncodingResourceWrapper(child, [GzipEncoderFactory()])
    return gzipChild
```

You'll also have to set up the `Realm`, `Checkers` and `Portal` as usual ([documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/http-auth.html)).